# Duplicate Key on Reactr Js Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So i have Autocomplete Material UI Component That render Data, the data from BE will be consume and grouped based on the first Letter, but when its being render on the Autocomplete component its become duplicate key error like this:
[image]

As you all can see, there is no duplicate at all but i keeps getting error message as below, here is my code:

```
const [dataSKU, setDataSKU] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    dataService.getAllSKU().then((response) => {
      setDataSKU(response.data.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    switch (event.key) {
      case ",":
      case " ": {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (event.target.value.length > 0) {
          setValue([...value, event.target.value]);
        }
        break;
      }
      default:
    }
  };
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("1");
  const [sku, setSku] = React.useState(" ");

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      padding: "0px",
    },
  }));

  const options = dataSKU.map((option) => {
    const firstLetter = option.sku_name[0].toUpperCase();

    return {
      firstLetter: /[0-9]/.test(firstLetter) ? "0-9" : firstLetter,
      ...option,
    };
  });

  return (
    <div className=" m-2 p-2 mr-2 bg-white h-screen ">
      <div className="text-left pl-2 pb-4 font-bold text-3xl">
        <h2>Find Material</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="p-2 align-left">
        <form
          className="flex items-center"
          onSubmit={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(sku.sku);
          }}
        >
          <Autocomplete
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
              option.value === value.value
            }
            style={{ width: "100%", color: "#ffffff" }}
            onChange={(event, newValue) => {
              setSku(newValue);
            }}
            id="grouped-demo"
            options={options.sort(
              (a, b) => -b.firstLetter.localeCompare(a.firstLetter)
            )}
            groupBy={(option) => option.firstLetter}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.sku_name}
            sx={{ width: 300 }}
            renderInput={(params) => {
              params.inputProps.onKeyDown = handleKeyDown;
              return <TextField {...params} label="Search by SKU" required />;
            }}
            renderGroup={(params) => (
              <ul key={params.key}>
                <li>
                  {console.log("params", params)}
                  <GroupHeader>{params.group}</GroupHeader>
                  <GroupItems>{params.children}</GroupItems>
                </li>
              </ul>
            )}
          />
          <div>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              color="success"
              variant="contained"
              style={{
                marginLeft: 10,
                width: "100%",
                height: 54,
              }}
              startIcon={<ContentPasteSearchIcon />}
            >
              Search
            </Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

is there a way to fix it?

Comment: The `key` prop that the error is happening on is not the one you pass to the `ul`. That can be removed. Rather, it's a `key` prop being set within `GroupItems`, which I assume is the returned list of running each item through `renderInput`. Can you put a `console.log` into the `renderInput` and see what the results are?

Comment: but it seems from the UL and LI from the console @MatthewHerbst

Comment: You were right, there were duplicate value...

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!